# asp.net MVC directory search

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am working on asp.net MVC application. I have a folder with some sub folders with following path structure:

```
\year_2011\year_2011\month_01\day_07\2011_01_07_ERU_SCA_13
\year_2011\year_2011\month_01\day_14\2011_01_14_SCA_ERU_14
\year_2011\month_01\day_16\2011_01_16_ERU_SCA_9
```

I have a jQuery datepicker and I need to check on datepicker's date selection that If there exists any xml file in curerent date name folder

suppose user picks 1st feburary 2011, I need to check if there exist any folder with name \year_2011 then I need to check if there exist any folder with name month_02 and day_01 and then 2011_02_01_ERU_SCA_xx and then see in that folder if there is any xml file with name abc.xml

My question is:

How can I go and check subfolder and match with selected date ?

Regards,
Asif Hameed

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't keep the organization of the files in a database, including the associated path?  You could simplify the storage of the files (say organize them simply the last subfolder since it encodes the year/month/day) and it might make it easier to determine if the appropriate file exists without having to search for files, say using a tag/date query against the db or cached db results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a DateTime instance which will hold the user selection:

```
public ActionResult Process(DateTime date)
{
    var path = Server.MapPath("~/");
    path = Path.Combine(path, "year_" + date.ToString("yyyy"));
    path = Path.Combine(path, "month_" + date.ToString("MM"));
    path = Path.Combine(path, date.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd_ERU_SCA_xx"));
    path = Path.Combine(path, "abc.xml");
    if (File.Exists(path))
    {
        // TODO: the file exists => do something with it
    }
    return View();
}
```

or as suggested by @Paulo Santos in the comments section you could also:

```
public ActionResult Process(DateTime date)
{
    var path = Server.MapPath(
        string.Format(
            "~/year_{0:yyyy}/month_{0:MM}/{0:yyyy}_{0:MM}_{0:dd}_ERU_SCA_xx/abc.xml",
            date
        )
    );
    if (File.Exists(path))
    {
        // TODO: the file exists => do something with it
    }
    return View();
}
```

Comment: thanks for quick response. Do I need to add this code in view or controller ?

Comment: @DotnetSparrow, in controller action which would be called by the client and passed the selected date.

Comment: why go through all this hassle? 
`path = Server.MapPath(date.ToString("~/'year_'yyyy/'month_'MM/yyyy_MM_dd'_ERU_SCA_xx/abc.xml'"))`

Comment: @Paulo Santos, yes good point. I will update my answer to include it.

Answer (score 1):

Figure out what the application root-relative path would be I.e.~/path/path/file.xml, and then use the Server.MapPath function to turn it into a filesystem path.  Then you can use System.IO.File.Exists(string) method to find out if it actually exists.

Sorry, should be formatting better but am on my phone.